# How to find conditional probability for the the given discrete random variable.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Consider a r.v. $X$ that takes values in the set Ω = {1, 2, 3, · · · , N} with equal probability. Determine $P(X > m)$ and $P(X > m + k | X > m)$ for integers m, k where $1 ≤ m < N$ and $m + k ≤ N$.

According to my understanding, $P(X > m)$ is straightforward = $1-m/N$.

Also, I know $P(X > m + k | X > m)$ = $P(X > m + k \cap X > m) / P(X > m)$.

But how to calculate $P(X > m + k \cap X > m)$? Or any other way to directly estimate the conditional probability $P(X > m + k | X > m)$?

Comment: $P(X>m+k \cap X>m) = P(X>m+k)$.

Comment: Yes even I though this to be so. But this presumes that $k>0$ which is not explicitly stated. It simply says that $k$ in integer.

Comment: Then in general it is equal to $P(X > \max\{m+k, m\})$.